# two rounded borders boxes in a row?

Tags: css

```
<style>
#firstname
{
border: 2px solid #3b5998;
padding: 10px 40px;
width: 100px;
background: #daf0ff;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="firstname">This is a box,This is a box,This is a box,This is a box,This is a box, </p><p id="firstname">This is a box,This is a box,This is a box,This is a box,This is a box,</p>
```

after viewing it on bowser it is showing boxes in different rows....how to bring them in same row ?

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried and researched so far? (Note that you can edit your question to add details, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `float: left` or `display: inline-block` on your `<p />` tags.

**Explanation:**
You are using block elements here (`<p />`). They will always force a line break except if you float them. You could use inline elements (such as `<span/>` to display them side by side but that would break the `padding`. So either `float` them or us the hybrid `display: inline-block`

Comment: glad it helped. it's good practice to accept the answer when after it is solved